# Remove one drive from Win 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I use Amazon Cloud and would prefer not to have One Drive active on my computer. Also, from a cleanliness standpoint I would like to remove the icon, etc. as well. However (and not surprisingly) it doesn't appear MSFT has made this an easy task. Does anyone know how to do this? Registry maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I found [a script on a German website](http://www.antary.de/2015/07/12/windows-10-onedrive-komplett-entfernen/). Copy this text into a txt file and rename it to RemoveOneDrive.cmd and run this cmd as admin:

```
@echo off
cls

set x86="%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe"
set x64="%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe"

echo OneDrive Prozess beenden
echo.
taskkill /f /im OneDrive.exe > NUL 2>&1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo OneDrive deinstallieren
echo.
if exist %x64% (
%x64% /uninstall
) else (
%x86% /uninstall
)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL 2>&1

echo OneDrive Überreste entfernen
echo.
rd "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "C:\OneDriveTemp" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1
rd "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft OneDrive" /Q /S > NUL 2>&1 

echo OneDrive im Datei Explorer entfernen
echo.
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /f > NUL 2>&1
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder" /f > NUL 2>&1

pause
```

This kills the OneDrive processes first, removes it and removes the entries from Windows Explorer.